# Boto3 SQS MD5OfMessageBody

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, md5

How does a python/boto3 sqs client get the MD5OfMessageBody? Is this generated by the client or received by the server? For example:

```
{
  "response": {
    "MD5OfMessageBody": "d73e2ed0c3817b077da8f9571426fb23",
    "MessageId": "69c3463d-0f60-4a1a-94d7-fb2949953b35",
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      "HTTPHeaders": {
        "access-control-allow-headers": "authorization,cache-control,content-length,content-md5,content-type,etag,location,x-amz-acl,x-amz-content-sha256,x-amz-date,x-amz-request-id,x-amz-security-token,x-amz-tagging,x-amz-target,x-amz-user-agent,x-amz-version-id,x-amzn-requestid,x-localstack-target,amz-sdk-invocation-id,amz-sdk-request",
        "access-control-allow-methods": "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "access-control-expose-headers": "etag,x-amz-version-id",
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "396",
        "content-type": "text/xml",
        "date": "Fri, 04 Aug 2023 11:26:40 GMT",
        "server": "hypercorn-h11"
      },
      "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
      "RequestId": "2834eec8-a1e4-4be3-b51f-127fe2e50205",
      "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see anything in the Boto3 client that seems to do this, but there's some MD5 init checks, it sounds like this is an actual response from SQS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the response, created by the service.

The [SQS SendMessage API](https://go.aws/45dDit9) creates the `MD5OfMessageBody` attribute, an MD5 digest of the non-URL-encoded message body string.

You can use this attribute to verify that Amazon SQS received the message correctly. Amazon SQS URL-decodes the message before creating the MD5 digest.

The below example demonstrates how to locally calculate the MD5 of a message and compare it with the MD5 returned by SQS:

```
import boto3
import hashlib

# Create message and calculate MD5
message = 'Hello World!'
client_side_md5 = hashlib.md5(message.encode()).hexdigest()
print(f'MD5 calculated locally: {client_side_md5}')


# Send message to SQS and get server-side MD5 from response
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='Fulfilment-Service-Queue')
response = queue.send_message(MessageBody=message)
service_side_md5 = response['MD5OfMessageBody']
print(f'MD5 calculated by SQS:  {service_side_md5}')

# Check if they match
if client_side_md5 == service_side_md5:
    print(f'Transmission succeeded.')
else:
    print(f'Error in transmission.')
```